# How to do non specialized type has method that accepts Function1?

Tags: scala, function, testing, mockito

I have the following class:

```
class Elem[T](t: T){
  def doSome(f: T => Unit):Unit = f(t)
}
```

So I want to test function invokation for the given `Elem` instance (I'm doing with mockito). When running the test

```
val f = mock(classOf[Int => Unit])
new Elem(1).doSome(f)
verify(f).apply(1)
```

I got the following exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
function1.apply$mcVI$sp(1);

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
function1.apply(1);
```

That's reasonable because `Function1` is specialized for `Int`. So making the test as

```
val f = mock(classOf[AnyRef => Unit])
new Elem(1.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).doSome(f)
verify(f).apply(1.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

works fine.

Is there a way to avoid this ugly casts to `AnyRef`? Maybe there is another tool more suitable for this case than mockito?

Comment: In the last code snippet, are both `asInstanceOf` really necessary, or is it sufficient if you do `new Elem(1)` and retain only the last `asInstanceOf`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Unfortunately, yes. Removing of these casts makes the test does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to force the compiler to use the non-specialized generic `apply`:

```
  def verifyGenericApply[X, Y](f: X => Y, x: X): Unit = {
    verify(f).apply(x)
  }

  "Int function" should "invoke non-specialized apply" in {
    class Elem[T](t: T){
      def doSome(f: T => Unit):Unit = f(t)
    }
    val f = mock(classOf[Int => Unit])
    new Elem(1).doSome(f)
    verifyGenericApply(f, 1)
  }
```

I'm not familiar enough with `mockito` to guarantee that this is idiomatic, though...

Comment: Looks pretty much cute. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[ScalaMock](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock) seems to work out-of-the-box:

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers._
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalamock.scalatest._

class Elem[T](t: T){
  def doSome(f: T => Unit):Unit = f(t)
}

class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {

  "Elem.doSome" should "apply given function once" in {
    val f = mockFunction[Int, Unit]
    f.expects(1).returning({}).once
    new Elem(1).doSome(f)
  }
}

run(new ExampleSpec)
```